# Erro de digitação no tour

Tags: bug, status-pronto, formatação

Conforme [reportado](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211621/177950) no meta do SO em inglês, o nosso *tour* contém um pequeno erro de digitação:

> Nos níveis mais altos, você terá acesso às **ferramentas de moderação**especiais. Você poderá trabalhar ao lado de nossos moderadores da comunidade para manter o site focado e útil.

"ferramentas de moderação" deveria estar em negrito, mas como não há espaço entre o último asterisco e a palavra "especiais", ela está sendo renderizada tal como foi escrita (i.e. com duplo asterisco no início e no fim).

(Não sei se esse problema pode ser resolvido aqui ou lá, por isso resolvi reportar aqui também...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ver: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211890/130213

Isso será resolvido no próximo deploy.

> **Resposta original, em inglês:**
>
> See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211890/130213
>
> This will be fixed in the next deploy.